# Insert part of filename to beginning of lines within file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a directory that includes .fasta files, among others. Each fasta file has the following format:

```
OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta
OFAS000739-RA-EXON03_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta
OFAS001341-RA-EXON03_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta
OFAS001376-RA-EXON05_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta
```

Within each file, e.g., `OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta`, are DNA sequences with their associated headers:

```
>Anasa_tristis_comp16713_c0_seq1
ATATTACGTAGATTGTTCTTTAATTGTCTATGAGTTTCGGAGACAAGGCTCTGAATTTTAGGGTGTTGATCACCGAATGTTAGGATGAGTATTGTTGTGGCGACAATAAATATGAAACCTACAAGGTAACTTTTTGCCCTCATTGAGAAGACACAGCCGCATTTGAGCCTTTTTTCCTTGCACGCTGAGTTTTCCTTAAGA
>Anoplocnemis_curvipes_gi_512414836_gb_GAJV01001484.1
ATATTACGTAGATTGTTCTTTAATTGTCTATGAGTTTCGGAGACAAGGCTCTGAATTCTAGGGTGTTGATCACCGAATGTTAGGATGAGTATTGTTGTAGCGACAATAAATGTGAAACCTACAAGGTAACTTTTTGCCCTCATTGAGAAGACACAGCCGCATTTGAGCCTTTTTCCTTGCACGCTGAGTTTTTCGTAAGA
```

What I want to do is go through each .fasta file, extract part of the filename (format:OFAS######-RA-EXON##), and then insert that extracted portion to the beginning of each header after the `>` symbol. To follow the `OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta` example, I want the content within the file to look like the following:

```
>OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_Anasa_tristis_comp16713_c0_seq1
ATATTACGTAGATTGTTCTTTAATTGTCTATGAGTTTCGGAGACAAGGCTCTGAATTTTAGGGTGTTGATCACCGAATGTTAGGATGAGTATTGTTGTGGCGACAATAAATATGAAACCTACAAGGTAACTTTTTGCCCTCATTGAGAAGACACAGCCGCATTTGAGCCTTTTTTCCTTGCACGCTGAGTTTTCCTTAAGA
>OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_Anoplocnemis_curvipes_gi_512414836_gb_GAJV01001484.1
ATATTACGTAGATTGTTCTTTAATTGTCTATGAGTTTCGGAGACAAGGCTCTGAATTCTAGGGTGTTGATCACCGAATGTTAGGATGAGTATTGTTGTAGCGACAATAAATGTGAAACCTACAAGGTAACTTTTTGCCCTCATTGAGAAGACACAGCCGCATTTGAGCCTTTTTCCTTGCACGCTGAGTTTTTCGTAAGA
```

I've seen some options online, but these are taking the entire filename and inserting at the beginning of each line. I'm a bit more familiar with sed, and I've got a bash script as a starting point, that I ***think*** gets me close to what I want. I could be way off, or there may be an easier way. I just don't know how to modify what I currently have to extract and/or use that portion of the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in OFAS* 
do 
    sed -i "s/>/>$f_/" "$f" 
done
```

Comment: Could you make this into a [mcve] for us? Thanks. (Specifically, *minimal*)

Comment: Also, could you zip up a few files so I can use them for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the needed part from the filename, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in OFAS* 
do 
    part=$(echo "$f" | sed 's/_rbh.*fasta$//')
    sed -i '.old' "s/^>/>${part}_/" "$f" 
done
```

In the above i just removing the `_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta` part from every filename.

Comment: I'm getting the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: \`.'` Might be due to my using gnu-sed on macOS?

Comment: try add `-e` e.g. `sed -i '.old' -e "s/^>/>${part}_/" "$f" `

Comment: Now getting `sed: can't read .old: No such file or directory`

Comment: hm.. sorry then. I don't have installed gnu-sed on my macOS. you can always use the full path name e.g. `/usr/bin/sed` - The answer works with the default `sed` on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in OFAS* 
do 
    sed -i "s/>/>${f%%_*}_/" "$f" 
done
```

${f%%**} will remove the longest pattern "**" from f, eg:

```
f=OFAS000562-RA-EXON01_rbh.fasta_results.txt.fasta
echo ${f%%_*}
```

gives:

```
OFAS000562-RA-EXON01
```

Comment: Me prefering using a helper variable (cos in the future allows easier modification of the extraction using different patterns) but yes - in this particular case this is better as my `sed`. +1 from me. :)